# Java regex help needed to split string please! How to ignore an empty line?

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm a complete noob to regex and I need help with splitting a string. I am inputing the following data

```
665  11% R     1    908K    388K  fg root     top
 61   1% S    42 152404K  29716K  fg system   system_server
 38   0% S     1    840K    340K  fg root     /system/bin/qemud
114   0% S    16 120160K  19156K  fg radio    com.android.phone
```

which is nothing but your regular top output. What I intend to do is select on entries like

```
655 11% R 1 fg root top
```

Now the code which I use to do the following is

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
{
  String[] segs= inputLine.split("[ ]+");
  str[i] = segs[0]+" "+segs[1]+" "+segs[2]+" "+
           segs[3]+" "+segs[6]+" "+segs[7]+" "+segs[8];
  Log.v("TOP Output", str[i]);
  i++; j++;
}
```

But the problem I face is, that I get on logcat is

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Where am I going wrong, and what could I do different to prevent this. Thanks for helping.

EDIT: After reading the comments I realize i have a couple of empty line in my output. So in such a case how am I supposed to ignore those line. I know I am supposed to match a case, but I am not sure about the expression or syntax!

Comment: First, examine the contents of the `segs` array. How many elements does it split into?

Comment: you may be reading an empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: Actually I am reading an empty line, but then in that case will it really matter?

Comment: Does it not initialize from zero, or am I supposed to start from 1!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the character class (square brackets). Space is a regular character in regex, so:

```
String[] segs = inputLine.split(" +");
```

Other than that, *assuming* array indices are there without range checking is bad style and an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is just what you've asked for.

Better do it explicitly:

```
String re = "^\\s*(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s*$";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourInputString);

while (m.find())
{
   // do stuff with m.group(1) through m.group(9)
}
```

This way it is guaranteed that every line you match fulfills your expectations and every matcher group contains what you expect, too.

*Disclaimer: I'm not especially proud of that regex. It's quite an ugly one, actually, but  it illustrates the point that explicit is more reliable and predictable than implicit. And it has the potential to be improved into a version that matches the desired parts even more accurately than a string split ever could.*

Comment: I am sorry I don't exactly understand understand what am I doing in your find function. I am pretty new to java, and am just picking up as I go along. Also does this take care of blank line, I would like to eliminate them from my result...

Comment: Also I got an invalid sequence error for String re in eclipse. What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: Whoops. These backslashes must be escaped. My bad, see corrected answer. Look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html for more reading on Java Regexes.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I got that, some more errors were there, I will put the code in the question. But selected your answer! thanks, shouvik...

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regexp, and check for array's length, every line!
And also consider using a StringBuilder or StringBuffer instead of concatenating.

```
 String[] s = inputLine.split("[\\s\\t]+");
```

Comment: If I have an empty line, how will this help me reject this line in my string entry?

Comment: Add a condition => (line != null && line.trim().length() > 0)

Comment: FYI, you don't need to match `\t` explicitly; `\s` has that covered.

Comment: @Alan Moore I thought the behaviour was that too. But when i tested it against the string "665  11% R     1    908K    388K  fg root     top", it returned me 25 strings, but later i realized that i had forgotton to add the "+" sign :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How consistent is this output?  Is there always a value in every column?  If so, try this:

```
line = line.replaceFirst("(?:\s+\d+[KM]?){3}", "");
```

You don't have to worry about blank lines with this approach, because the regex doesn't match them.

Answer (score 0):

be careful at str instantiation, how big is it, because it's an array. You should use a list or anything else, because you don't know how many lines you have in your input.

Comment: I suppose str it's an array of String